# $A$ and $B$ are rectangular matrices such that $AB$ is invertible, prove that $BA$ isn't.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $m \neq n$

I believe I understand the problem, but I can't come up with a good, formal proof for this..

Answer (score 3):

Assume by contradiction that $AB=I_m$ and $BA=I_n$ for non-square matrices.

Case 1: $m>n$. Define $A', B'$ to be $m \times m$ matrices the following way:

$$A'= \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \end{pmatrix} \,;\, B'= \begin{pmatrix} B \\ 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Then $A'B'= I_m$ but 
$B'A'=\begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ 
0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $. Contradiction.

Case 2: $m<n$. Define $A', B'$ to be $n \times n$ matrices the following way:

$$A'= \begin{pmatrix} A \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \,;\, B'= \begin{pmatrix} B & 0\end{pmatrix} $$

Then $B'A'=\begin{pmatrix} I_m & 0 \\ 
0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $ but 
$B'A'=I_n $. Contradiction.

I both cases, the contradiction is the fact that for **square matrices** $A'B'=I$ implies that $B'A'=I$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Think about whether $m > n$ or $n > m$. (*Further hint:* Consider ranks.)

Comment: Yeah, I've come as far as that, but I want to formalize it one step more. I understand that $m < n$ and that $rank \, A = rank \, B = m$ etc, but I fail to prove it nicely and formally..

Answer (score 1):

A $k \times k$ matrix is invertible if and only if it has rank $k$, and $k$ is the maximum possible rank for a $k \times k$ matrix.  Also, if you have two matrices $A,B$, then $rank(AB) \leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))$